# ms access select into with fixed value for one field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have sourceTable which contains one field sourceNum.  I want to import it into another table called newTable that has two fields: sourceNum and type.  I want type to equal "solid" for every record in newTable.  How do I write that in Access 2010 compliant sql code?

So far I have:

```
SELECT sourceNum, type INTO NewTable 
FROM (SELECT sourceNum FROM sourceTable)
```

How do I alter this code so that it results in newTable populated with two fields as described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT sourceNum, 'solid' AS type INTO NewTable 
FROM sourceTable
```

Comment: Will this syntax not throw an error since the NewTable already exists

Comment: @MuhammedAli in that case it will, but OP question was specifically about "select into" - the assumption the query is creating new table

Comment: OP Question " I want to import it into another table called newTable that has two fields: sourceNum and type" , from this what I understand  the table already exists

Comment: @MuhammedAli that still could mean newTable is created by the query. But no sense guessing semantics, let OP chose whatever works for him best

Comment: It was just a suggestion pal take it easy :)

Comment: I am at ease :) the question kinda unclear, but one of our solutions should fit either way.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (sourceNum, Type)
SELECT sourceNum, 'solid' 
FROM sourceTable
```